# How to process the multi dimensional array into specific array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want the array to be processed into my final array how am I supposed to achieve this? Below is the array that I have which I got from the loop.

```
Array 
(
    Array
      (
          [part_id] => 2338117
          [supplier] => COOLDRIVE DISTRIBUTION
          [quantity] => 12
      )
    Array
      (
          [part_id] => 2338117
          [supplier] => ROLAN
          [quantity] => 20
      )
    Array
      (
          [part_id] => 51154
          [supplier] => ROLAN
          [quantity] => 20
      )
)
```

into the final array.

```
Array
(
    [COOLDRIVE DISTRIBUTION] => Array 
          (
              [proudctID] => Array 
                     (
                         [0] => 2338117
                     )
           )
    [ROLAN] => Array 
           (
               [productID] => Array 
                  (
                       [0] => 2338117
                       [1] => 51154
                  )
           )
)
```

Comment: _"these arrays which I got from the loop"_ - what loop? If you arrange your data the way you want it in there already (which should most likely be possible), you don't have to do it afterwards.

Comment: Just loop over this data, and populate a new array, using the `supplier` value as key on the first level, and below that the static text `proudctID` as second level key.

Comment: Also provide data with var_export(), so it can be used.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @CBroe as u can see in the first array there are three arrays nested  so what I want to do next is make an array which is the final array that has supplier as 'key' and also merge the arrays that has same supplier name

Comment: I don't need you to repeat what you want using only slightly different words, that was clear from the beginning already. But you probably don't need to create the first array first, and then _transform_ it into the second one; likely this can be done in the loop that created the first array already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this in your case. Considering your old array as $oldarr

```
$newarr = array();

foreach($oldarr as $value){
    $newarr[$value['supplier']]['productID'][] = $value['part_id'];
}
print_r($newarr);
```